# Highlight or underline search words in WordPress Editor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, tinymce

I have a plugin that warns users about certain words in their posts that maybe shouldn't be used. Currently, it simply lists these words at the bottom of the editor window while they're writing or editing their post.

What I would like is to highlight the offending words so they can easily find them (especially if they just pasted a large block of text). I found a couple jquery plugins ([Highlight Textarea](https://github.com/garysieling/jquery-highlighttextarea) and [Highlight Within Textarea](https://github.com/lonekorean/highlight-within-textarea)) but neither of those seem to work in this case (probably due to the dynamic size of the textarea). Any ideas? Is there a way to do this through TinyMCE?

Googling it just brings up a bunch of answers on how to manually highlight text to be highlighted in your post. I want the opposite: an automatic highlighter that only highlights in the editor, not the post. Oh, and it should work on both the Visual and Text views...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a complete answer with code, but it sounds like you should take a look at mark.js https://markjs.io/ and target the editor `div` in the post editor in WordPress.

> mark.js is a text highlighter written in JavaScript. It can be used to
>   dynamically mark search terms or custom regular expressions and offers
>   you built-in options like diacritics support, separate word search,
>   custom synonyms, iframes support, custom filters, accuracy definition,
>   custom element, custom class name and more.

There are many examples on that page to work with.